# Variables in Start-Job do not get evaluated

Tags: powershell

My Powershell code doesn't evaluate the `$agent` variable:

```
foreach ($agent in $agentcomputers) {
    Write-Output 'Starting agent on '$agent
    # psexc to start the agent
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& psexec $agent c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd}
}
```

[This link](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/29/powershell-start-job-scriptblock-sad-panda-face) is similar to my problem, except I'm not calling an external Powershell script.

I tried adding that in, using `$args[0]` for `$agent`, and adding the `-ArgumentList` parameters, but that didn't work.

---

**Edits/Replies**

`$agentcomputers` is just a list of computer names - each on its own line:

```
$agentcomputers = Get-Content c:\grinder-dist\agent-computers.txt
```

I have also tried this - and `$args[0]` doesn't evaluate:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& psexec $args[0] c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd} -ArgumentList @($agent)
```

Comment: You will need to use the ArgumentList parameter either using the `$args` array or a param block.

Comment: You might also change the scope of your $agent variable, I think: $global:agent.

Comment: @DavidBrabant the global scope won't work since it's executed in a seperate PowerShell.exe process. The data is serialized and passed to the background process.

Comment: How are you sure that $agent isn't evaluated? If you change psexec with a test write-output $agent you have same behaviour? No error output?

Comment: It seems as if the $agent is being omitted altogether.  The PSExec command runs the process on my local computer.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - can you look at the second edit above with the -ArgumentList parameter?

Comment: You may need backslashes acording to psexec's [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) `"\\$args[0]"`. Make sure the command works by itself without a background job.

Comment: yes, I realized that after @Christian comment and looking at it a bit harder.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution.  As Andy said, I needed to use $args array with the -ArgumentList parameter.  This other thread was helpful:  [Powershell: passing parameters to a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472284/powershell-passing-parameters-to-a-job)

```
foreach($agent in $agentcomputers){
$agentslash = "\\"+$agent
$args = ($agentslash,"c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd")
Write-Output 'Starting agent on '$agent

#psexc to start the agent
$ScriptBlock = {& 'psexec' @args } 

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $args

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here are 3 different ways I would do it. 
First, all aligned and pretty.

```
$agents = Get-Content c:\grinder-dist\agent-computers.txt
$jobs = {
     Param($agent)
         write-host "Starting agent on" $agent
         & psexec \\$agent c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd
}
foreach($agent in $agents) {
     Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobs -argumentlist $agent | Out-Null
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Or you could just put it all on one line without creating any variables.

```
(Get-Content c:\grinder-dist\agent-computers.txt) | %{ Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($_) write-host "Starting agent on" $_; & psexec \\$_ c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd } -argumentlist $_ | Out-Null }
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

And in this final example, you could manage how many threads are run concurrently by doing it this way.

```
$MaxThreads = 5
$agents = Get-Content c:\grinder-dist\agent-computers.txt
$jobs = {
     Param($agent)
         write-host "Starting agent on" $agent
         & psexec \\$agent c:\grinder\examples\startAgent.cmd
}
foreach($agent in $agents) {
     Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobs -argumentlist $agent | Out-Null
     While($(Get-Job -State 'Running').Count -ge $MaxThreads) {
          sleep 10
     }
     Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
}
```