# PowerShell and global functions

Tags: function, powershell, global

Why is the following code not working? According to this article the usage of global should be correct: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730957.aspx

```
Function global:writeLog {
    param($logType, $logString, $logFile)

    $fileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream $logFile ,'Append','Write','Read'
    $streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $fileStream

    $time = get-date -Format "hh:mm:ss"
    $streamWriter.writeLine("[${time}][$logType] ${logString}")

    $streamWriter.close()

}

$temp = {
    writeLog -logType "INFO" -logString "Test" -logFile "d:\scripts\powershell\logtest.txt"
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $temp 
get-job | receive-job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

This is the exception that powershell throws

```
The term 'writeLog' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (writeLog:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: Does your `$temp{ writeLog ... }` exist for anything other than passing arguments? Instead pass the arguments directly from `Start-Job` to the function using the `ArgumentList` parameter, skipping the middle-man.

Comment: Write a more precise question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell jobs actually run in a separate PowerShell process.  You can see this like so:

```
$pid
Start-Job {$pid} | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Where `$pid` is the current PowerShell's process id.

Anything that needs to be accessed from the script that runs in the job, must be either defined in the scriptblock passed to Start-Job i.e. function defined in the script block or as parameters passed into the script block using the `-ArgumentList` parameter on Start-Job or the script can dot source another script (or import a module) that contains the functions it needs.  Personally, I would put shared functions in a module like Utils.psm1 and then import like so:

```
Start-Job {param($scriptdir) Import-Module $scriptdir\Utils.psm1; ...} -Arg $PSScriptRoot
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `Start-Job`:

> A Windows PowerShell background job runs a command "in the background" without interacting with the current session.

Therefor, the current session scope is ignored.

Trivial Solution: Define the function inside the scriptblock.

```
$JobScript = { 
    function write-log {
        ....
    }
    write-log <parameters>
}
```

Alternatively, check these related questions:

[Powershell: passing parameters to a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472284/powershell-passing-parameters-to-a-job)

[Variables in Start-Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196489/variables-in-start-job)

Answer (score 2):

Define the function in a script block, then use

1. Invoke-Command with NoNewScope to get it in the current scope
2. The InitializationScript parameter to get it into the job

```bsh
#Create Shared Functions Script Block
[scriptblock] $func = {function getPID() {write-output "Function Running in process id: $pid!"}}

#Set up functions in normal script scope so they're accessible here
Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $func

write-output "Main script started"

#run the function from the parent script
getPID

#Create background job script
$jobScript = {getPID}

#Run background job
write-output "starting background job"
Start-Job $jobScript -name "Job1" -InitializationScript $func

get-job | Receive-Job
get-job | Stop-Job
get-job | Remove-Job
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing Global functions. Late, but it works today 9/28/23

```
Function Global:MyDisplay{
     Write-Host "Wahoo!" -ForegroundColor Green

}

Save to a file: Test.ps1
Call the file: Test.ps1
Type Function Name: MyDisplay

Display output: Wahoo!
```