# Passing parameters to a remote scriptblock

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-7.0

Say i have 2 scripts. main-script.ps1 and base-script.ps1 and base-script being called from main-script.

```
#base-script.ps1
Param(
    [string]$Site,
    [string]$Env,
    [string]$Package,
    [bool]$New_Variable,
    [string]$New_Variable2
)
Write-Host "i am in base script"
Write-Host " i am in server " $env:COMPUTERNAME

Write-Host $Site
Write-Host $Env
Write-Host $Package
Write-Host $New_Variable
Write-Host $New_Variable2
```

```
#main-script.ps1
Param(
    [string]$SiteName,
    [string]$Environment,
    [string]$PackageName

)
Write-Host "I am in main-script"

$new_var = $true
$new_var2 = "Green"

$deployToBaseBlock = get-command '.\Base-script.ps1' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScriptBlock

Invoke-Command S1 -ScriptBlock $deployToBaseBlock -ArgumentList $SiteName,$Environment,$PackageName,$new_var,$new_var2

Write-Host "I am back in main. exiting"
```

Now as the parameters in base-script.ps1 grows, the arguments being passed in argumentlist is getting long and unmanageable. Is there a better way to do this. I wasnt able to get splatting work on this.

According to the first comment, we need to try something like this:

```
start-job -scriptblock { & 'c:\ps\bcpCopy.ps1' @args } -ArgumentList $ARGS
```

but in my case, scriptblock is defined outside.

```
$deployToBaseBlock = get-command '.\Base-script.ps1' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScriptBlock

Invoke-Command S1 -ScriptBlock {$deployToBaseBlock @args} -ArgumentList $arr
```

$arr is the array of arguments. This doesnt seem to work. Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: passing parameters to a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472284/powershell-passing-parameters-to-a-job), See [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

Comment: in the given example, the script is being called inside the script-block like this:
start-job  -scriptblock {
    & 'c:\ps\bcpCopy.ps1' @args } -ArgumentList $ARGS

in my case, scriptblock is defined outside the scriptblock:

$deployToBaseBlock = get-command '.\Base-script.ps1' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScriptBlock

so this doesnt seem to work:
Invoke-Command S1 -ScriptBlock {$deployToBaseBlock @args} -ArgumentList $arr, 

$arr being array of arguments

Comment: Please do not add code in a comment because that becomes unreadable. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63533452/edit) you rquestion and paste it there as [Formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote endpoint will need to re-create and re-compile the scriptblock anyway, so you might as well just pass it the raw `Base-Script.ps1` *file*.

Fortunately `Invoke-Command` already has a parameter for this exact use case:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath '.\Base-script.ps1' -ComputerName S1 -ArgumentList $arr
```